# How to susbstuite the string from the dictionary values

Tags: python

My parent dictionary is below

```
d = 
[{"code":1, "description":"This is only one %s", "name":"Hello"},
"code":2, "description":"This %s has one more %s", "name":"World"}]
```

My input
`{'code':1, 'details':['A']}`

Expected out
`{"description":"This is only one A", "name":"Hello"}`

My input
`{'code':2, 'details':['A','B']}`

Expected out
`{"description":"This A has one more B", "name":"World"}`

- There is `%s` in the description
- it has to replace by the values inside the `details` key

Comment: do i need to change %s to any other format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass your `values` as a tuple of objects, you can use `%s` and string formatting.

```
d=[{"code":1, "description":"This is only one %s", "name":"Hello"},
{"code":2, "description":"This %s has one more %s", "name":"World"}]

def replace(code, values):
    for row in d:
        if row.get('code', None) == code:
            return {
                'description': row['description'] % (values),
                'name': row['name'],
            }
    return 'Code not Found'

>>> replace(1, ('A'))
{'description': 'This is only one A', 'name': 'Hello'}
>>> replace(2, ('A', 'B'))
{'description': 'This A has one more B', 'name': 'World'}
>>>
```